Excel - expand spilled range for VLOOKUP
I have a VLOOKUP where I would like to expand the range.
This is the formula i tried:
=VLOOKUP("my_value",A2#,2,0)
A2# is just one column, and I have the return values in the adjacent column, but obviously it does not work as my range is only 1 column.
Is it possible to expand the lookup range dynamically to include that column?
As an alternative I am aware that I could just use 'A:B' as my range
=VLOOKUP("my_value",A:B,2,0)
but I would prefer just to expand my lookup range.

Yes, you can. But A:B would be most easier.

Why are you trying to create a problem that doesn't really exist in the first place?  First of all, use XLOOKUP, it's better and easier to maintain, secondly, just name your range/insert table and everything just works.

Yeah I agree with @Michal Sir here using XLOOKUP() will be pretty  easier and simpler. But when you use VLOOKUP() with A:B it will be calculating empty regions as well, thus slowing down the working functionality of Excel. Also, since A2# is an array, you could try something like this using VLOOKUP() or XLOOKUP() but it depends on your data, as we don't see any sample here: using VLOOKUP() --> =VLOOKUP("my_value",HSTACK(A2#,INDEX(DROP(B:B,1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2#)))),2,0) or using XLOOKUP() --> =XLOOKUP("my_value",A2#, INDEX(DROP(B:B,1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2#))),"None")
